# Tensor Decomposition with respect to pair-wise swapping

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, representation-theory

Fix a 2 dimensional complex vector space $V$, and a basis for this vector space $\{\alpha, \beta\}$. The problem I am interested in is as follows: for the $k$th fold tensor product vector space $W= V^{\otimes k}$, one has a natural choice of basis obtained by taking all linear combinations of $\{\alpha, \beta\}^{\otimes k}$. Now suppose I have a linear operator on this space $M: W \rightarrow W$ defined as by its action on the basis vectors; $M$ acts by swapping the $i$th and $(i+1)$th entries of a basis vector only if the entries take different values. For example for $k=3$, $M$ can act as:

\begin{equation}
M(\alpha\otimes \beta \otimes \beta)= \beta \otimes \alpha \otimes \beta
\end{equation}
or another example:
\begin{equation}
M(\alpha\otimes \beta \otimes \alpha)= \beta \otimes \alpha \otimes \alpha +  \alpha \otimes \alpha\otimes \beta
\end{equation}
I would like to decompose $W$ into irreducible subspaces on which $M$ acts naturally. For example, any fully symmetrized combination of basis vectors is an eigenvector of $M$. I believe that this decomposition can be described in terms of Young Tableaux, but am not very well-versed on this.

Comment: Just to be clear of the definition of $M$, suppose we identify basis vectors with binary strings, eg $v_{00110}$ is a basis vector in $V^{\otimes 5}$. To compute $M(v_{00110})$, we generate all the pairwise swaps of the string $00110$, which are (in order) $00110$, $01010$, $00110$, and $00101$, and then we keep only those results which are not equal to the original string, so $M(v_{00110}) = v_{01010} + v_{00101}$. Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct interpretation.